# Angular4 - do I need to unsubscribe from setTimeout calls?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, settimeout

In a few places I have needed to call setTimeout, eg:

```
setTimeout(() => this.isSaving[index] = false, 500);
```

When my component is destroyed, will that timeout continue to emit? In other words do I need to capture the returned observable, like this:

```
this.subTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.isSaving[index] = false, 500);
```

and then unsub in my destroy hook:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subTimeout.unsubscribe();
}
```

This gets laborious if I have to initiate several setTimeouts in my component. Is there an easier way to destroy them all? Like maybe with takeUntil(destroy$)?

Comment: if you want a convenient way to do the takeUntil(destroy$) you could checkout this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737752/anuglar2-lifecycle-events-as-rxjs-observable/

Comment: Thanks, but I think, as you cannot subscribe to setTimeout you cannot use takeUntil(destroy$). Also that link you provided overcomplicates destroying subscriptions. You don't need decorators, you just need a subject: private destroy$ = new Subject();  ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
}

Comment: You could use `Observable.timer(1000)` instead of `setTimeout` if you want it to be observable. As to it overcomplicating it, I use the base class version and it simplifies the destruction since I don't have to track subscriptions or deal with null checks if they were created in ngOnInit. It also allows @Inputs to be observable via onChanges.

Comment: @bygrace Thanks, I didn't know about Observable.timer(1000).

Comment: @bygrace I see the advantage of the base class solution but I would now have to go through all my components, change them to inherit it and then go through each lifecycle hook I implemented to call super. Since I've already got next.destroy$ in them all, it's easier to keep it that way for now at least. But thanks for sharing that post, I gave it a +1 as it is useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> do I need to unsubscribe from setTimeout calls?...When my component is destroyed, will that timeout continue to emit?

You don't need to worry about the callback executing repeatedly. `setTimeout` executes just once then it's dead. It's generally good practice to account for the possibility that the time will run out and the callback execute only after the component has been destroyed though. In my own applications, I throw in an array all subscriptions that need to be undone, and I have a standard batch unsubscribe job in `ngOnDestroy`. The same can be done with your timeouts:

```
// component property
timeOutIDs:number[] = [];
...
// triggering a timeout and capturing the id
this.timeOutIDs.push(
    setTimeout(() => this.isSaving[index] = false, 500)
);
...
// inside ngOnDestroy
this.timeoutIDs.forEach(id => clearTimeout(id));
```

With this approach you won't need multiple variables to store different timeout ids, and you can be sure that all your timeouts will be cleared properly if you always `push` the return value of `setTimeout` in your ids array.

Additional note: You should always cancel `setInterval` calls and always unsubscribe from open-ended subscriptions though.

Comment: what happens if component gets disposed before `setTimeout` fires?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - and also pointing that for setInterval it is needed. I would have missed that. Open-ended subscriptions I learned about the hard way, lol ;)

Comment: @deezg The callback will still attempt to execute. If your timespan is long enough, you do need to address this possibility. The OP seemed concerned about a timeout that "continues to emit" so I answered with that in mind.

Comment: well, he asked ''When my component is destroyed, will that timeout continue to emit?". and simple answer is: yes. Not to mention good practice of cleaning it regardless of delay set into it. To be on the save side, he would be using `Observable.timer` if he don't want to think about these kind of things.

Comment: you might want to integrate this little talk in comments into your answer so we can upvote it ;)

Comment: you're welcome! thank you for very nice cleaning procedure you've shown!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what's going on inside `setTimeout` callbacks, but generally they should be unsubscribed. There's no way how they could be magically be unsubscribed. Their callbacks will be fired any way and may cause errors or undesirable side effects.

It is a good practice to make timeout be assigned somewhere, at least for the purpose of testing. The thing that is supposed to be done in `ngOnDestroy`, `this.subTimeout.unsubscribe()` presumes that a timeout is performed through RxJS:

```
this.subTimeout = Observable.timer(500).subscribe(() => { 
  this.isSaving[index] = false;
});
```

The way it can be improved depends on what purpose these timeouts serve.